# Fetching Alchemist, Grand Potion I

Tags: mathematics, optimization, graph-theory, video-games

[image]

This is a puzzle in the [Fetching Alchemist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.bizleycraft.fetchingalchemist) series.

There's no selling in this puzzle, just one potion to brew, but with a lot of ingredients.

Please note that, in my opinion, imperfect solutions should be up-voted so long as they work and are lower than previous guesses. This makes them useful, since they inform other players of whether they have a possible solution or not.

---

### How to Play

You are looking for the shortest possible path that allows you to complete all the quests. You choose where you start. The red numbers indicate the distance of each road. Present your answer in the form "99: ABCDE...", where the numbers are the total path distance and the letters are the place you started at followed by the places you visit on the path.

You complete a quest by either starting there or travelling there with the required items in your inventory, which are consumed upon completing the quest (if the quest has required items, indicated by the presence of items left of an arrow under the quest).

The items drawn around places are the reward items for the quests that can be completed there.

You can complete a quest more than once but only once per place.

You cannot avoid completing a quest that you are able to complete where you are. This includes when you have no need for the quest reward.

You can complete more than one quest in the same place. When completing more than one quest in the same place, quests are completed automatically from top to bottom. Consequently, completing a higher quest may prevent completing a lower quest.

If you would obtain an item from completing a quest, you can use it to complete a quest in the same place without travelling again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so...

> AOPISH clocks in at 59.  I *think* that's as good as you're going to get.  C isn't workable because it's just too expensive to get both the blood and the rattles.  Trying to go to Q for the brewing almost works, but taking the trail the other way is slightly faster.  Getting the rattles at B and going for H almost works, but there's no easily accessible sage.

Comment: Really well done